# SFTP Inbound channel Adapter does not copy file when local directory has any content

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to use Spring Batch Integration with Spring Batch programs that I have constructed already, but at this point I am just trying to get a working sample of Spring Integration with help from [Spring IO](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound) and the [Spring Example on GITHUB](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/SftpInboundReceiveSample-context.xml).

I have customized the sample program to copy all the files on the remote directory to local at one shot, and few other subtle changes. The program works pretty much fine, though it works *if and only if* the local directory I am copying to has no content in it.

I tried to rename the files and run the program but still the same issue. Even if the local directory has the hidden .DS_Store file the program does not copy the contents i.e., files from the remote (SFTP) directory. I would like to try out few scenarios:

1. Copy files even if there are hidden files
2. Overwrite the files with the same name
3. Copy only a subset of files i.e., copy only the files that are not already with the same name

Pardon my ignorance, I seem to miss out setting some property on the  tag.

My XML file is pretty much as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:user.properties"/>

    <bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="22"/>
        <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    </bean>

    <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
            channel="receiveChannel"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            local-directory="file:${local.directory}"
            remote-directory="${remote.directory}"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            filename-pattern="*.txt">
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="-1" fixed-rate="1000" />
    </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="receiveChannel">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>

</beans>
```

Here's the Test program:

```
public class SftpInboundReceiveSampleTest {

    @Test
    public void runDemo(){
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/integration/SftpInboundReceiveSample-context.xml", this.getClass());
        PollableChannel localFileChannel = context.getBean("receiveChannel", PollableChannel.class);
        System.out.println("Received first file message: " + localFileChannel.receive());
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Operating System: Mac OS X 10.9.3
Spring Integration version: 4.0.0.RELEASE
Log: [here](http://pastebin.com/HG7fftiv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been reported before that files are not copied if the local directory is not empty, but I don't see in the code how that's possible and we have never been able to reproduce the issue. I don't recall the outcome of the previous question(s).

So:

1. Should just work - can you turn on DEBUG logging to see if it provides any clues? Please also indicate operating system and Spring Integration version.
2. Files are always copied (by default) and overwrite the local version; however, they won't generate messages if the file is already processed by this instance of the app (the default local-filter is an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`). Since 3.0, you can set the `local-filter` to an `AcceptAllFileListFilter` to always generate a message - but you need to remove the file when it's processed to avoid it being found over and over again on every poll. Or, use a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` which stores the lastModified date as well as the file name, so can detect the file has changed.
3. In order to prevent duplicate files being fetched (regardless of #2), instead of a `filename-pattern`, use a `CompositeFileListFilter` that delegates to (a) an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` and an `SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter`; the file will only be fetched if it passes both filters.

PS: I just ran a test on OS X to a directory `/Users/foo/bar` where bar has a `.DS_Store` and it worked just fine.

EDIT:

Here is my config that does 1, 2, and 3...

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
        channel="receiveChannel"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        local-directory="/Users/.../Development/tmp"
        remote-directory="foo"
        auto-create-local-directory="true"
        delete-remote-files="false"
        filter="filter">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="receiveChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

<bean id="filter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore" />
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg value="foo" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg value="*.txt" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

...
// logs showing existing present files sent to the channel
...
16:44:54.465 WARN  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] Permanently added '10.0.0.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
16:45:06.372 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer] 2 files transferred
16:45:12.704 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter] Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
16:45:40.056 DEBUG [task-scheduler-4][org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer] 0 files transferred
```

Notice the `2 files transferred` and `0 files transferred`.

I don't see any logs for `SftpInboundFileSynchronizer` in your logs. Note that I had to put a sleep in the test app - if you are using the same app; it terminates before synchronizing any files if files exist already; put a `Thread.sleep()` in there to stop it terminating.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with the requested information.

Comment: Updated the answer with some suggestions.

Comment: Note also that we don't fetch any remote files until we've processed all the existing local files (or they are filtered).

Comment: My Goodness, with just the same program I had initially everything works fine if I only add Thread.sleep(1000). I seem to be missing something really fundamental here. Could you please provide me some pointers on why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: It's the way JUnit works - when `runDemo` exits, the test is terminated. If you make it a `main()` method it will run forever (until you kill it, or close the `ApplicationContext`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56307/discussion-between-oneworld-and-gary-russell).